# Android TwoWayView Import and Usage

Tags: android, import

For 4 days now I have been trying to get this  TwoWayView Library to work in Eclipse. I am not sure if the issue is me or Eclipse. Since I updated Eclipse two weeks ago it has been nothing but a nightmare. Anyways, I downloaded the TwoWayView Project from GitHub, Imported into Eclipse as existing Code, Set project as Library. That should be it for the TwoWayView Lib.

In my project I Right Click> Properties> Android> Add> (Select TwoWayView)> Apply>.

I have Right Click> Properties>  Project> Add TwoWayView>.

So far, nothing. I have read in 3 blogs about how simple it should be by just importing the project and using it. Even Lucas' instructions are 3 steps and for the life of me can't figure out how in the world it could sound so simple yet I can't get it to work at all. Has anyone got this to work and if so, HOW?

Comment: hi.. is it working for you now.. I too have same problem here..

Answer (score 3):

you could try using gradle, simply add this line to your dependencies in build.gradle: compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.1'

Answer (score 1):

Just today I had the same problem as you, but I'm working with Android Studio, but I hope you serve.

It turns out that the content of the project is not the library, are just some of the folders that are within `twoway-view-master` so you have to go one by one and only necessary. Only you need to include the following folders:

1. `core`
2. `layouts`

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Download the library project [TwoWayView of Lucasr](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view)
2. Create, in your Android project you're working in a new folder. In `C:\Users\your-user\AndroidStudioProjects\your-name-of-application\` create a new folder called `libraries`.
3. Within the `libraries` folder created, paste the library project TwoWayView you just downloaded (`twoway-view-master` folder).
4. In the project tree of our IDE us that new folder (`libraries`) will appear. Access the `settings.gradle` of `libraries` and add the following lines of code:

   `include ': app'`

   `include ': libraries: twoway-view-master: core'`

   `include ': libraries: twoway-view-master: layouts'`
5. Now go to the `libraries/ twoway-view-master/core` and access `build.gradle` folder. Change this line of code:

   `apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/scripts/gradle-mvn-push.gradle"`

By the following:

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/libraries/twoway-view-master/gradle/scripts/gradle-mvn-push.gradle"
```

6. Perform step 5 but this time with the `build.gradle` file `layouts` folder.
7. In the `build.gradle` file `layouts` folder, you also have to change the line:

   `compile project (':core')`

By the following:

```
compile project (':libraries:twoway-view-master:core')
```

8. Finally you just have to access the `build.gradle` of your project and add the following lines in the section `dependencies`:

   `compile project (':libraries:twoway-view-master:core')`

   `compile project (':libraries:twoway-view-master:layouts')`

If you do not understand very well what to do, this question is the solution that gives the user [prudhvi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3701433/prudhvi).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402832/6129931

**EDIT:** However, since Google launched the Android version L, exist the called RecyclerView, there that can do everything you do with TwoWayView, i.e. can create lists and grids in horizontally and vertically.  I recommend you reports about it rather than use separate libraries because Google is starting to demand their use.

Here you can get information about RecyclerView use in horizontal and vertical:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355506/learn-step-by-step-to-use-the-recyclerview-in-android - StackOverflow

Hope this can help you.