# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found when trying to import project as library into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, build-error

I checked all the other threads about this topic but couldn't find an answer.
I am trying to import the [Twoway View](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) Project as a library into **Android Studio**.

Both projects run fine on their own but I always get the same Gradle Error: **Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found** when trying to import.

I have the project copied into a "**libraries**" directory in the root folder of my project and the following gradle structure:

settings.gradle of my project:

```
include ':libraries:twoway-view-master',':app'
```

build.gradle of "app":

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.jeldrik.teacherslittlehelper"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':libraries:twoway-view-master')
```

and in twoway-view-master build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That **twowayview-master build.gradle** file isn't a buildscript for a standalone module; it lacks any sort of `apply plugin` statement that would tell Gradle how it should compile something. This looks like the top-level build file of a multimodule-structured project. In your **settings.gradle** file, you should point at the module in the project you're trying to include, not the build file at the top level.

Comment: okay... but how do you point ?? can you say what a "module in a project" is

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it out using File -> New Module?

Or try setting the dependencies from here as well : File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I have recently got into same issue. As Scott said we have to include individual modules in our project's `build.gradle` file. This `TwoWayView` library has 3 different modules

1. core
2. layouts
3. sample

Say if you want to add `core` and `layouts`, add the below lines in your project's `build.gradle` file (Assuming you have `twoway-view-master` folder inside `libraries` folder which is inside your app folder).

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':your-app-folder:libraries:twoway-view-master:core')
    compile project(':your-app-folder:libraries:twoway-view-master:layouts')
}
```

Then add the same path to your project's `settings.gradle` file

```
include ':your-app-folder:libraries:twoway-view-master:core'
include ':your-app-folder:libraries:twoway-view-master:layouts'
```

**NOTE:** The `build.gradle` files inside `core` and `layouts` have wrong path  to `gradle-mvn-push.gradle` file. So change the path from

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/scripts/gradle-mvn-push.gradle"
```

to

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/your-app-folder/libraries/twoway-view-master/gradle/scripts/gradle-mvn-push.gradle"
```

If you still get error in layouts' `build.gradle` file, change this line

```
compile project(':core')
```

to

```
compile project(':your-app-folder:libraries:twoway-view-master:core')
```

Do the same change if you're also using sample's `build.gradle` file in your project.